# Fill the selected row so that they have equal numbers of non-NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

[image: The flowchart for the algorithm]

My flowchart is illustrated as above, I want to take 2 rows from the original dataset, then import them to another(because I don't want to modify the original data). In the new dataset, check if 2 rows have the same number of non-NaN value (`df.iloc[i,:].count()`), if not, fill the difference in number by zero, and then continue to perform the operation.

Example: 
Original Data:

```
3    5    5    NaN  NaN  NaN
1    4    7    5    NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  3    6    7    NaN
NaN  3    8    4    11   NaN
3    0    3    7    2    1
```

Take 2 row i and i+1 and import them to another dataset:

```
3    5    5    NaN  NaN  NaN
1    4    7    5    NaN  NaN
```

Because `df.iloc[i+1,:].count() != df.iloc[i,:].count()` , then the row with more NaN value must be filled like this:

```
3    5    5    0    NaN  NaN
1    4    7    5    NaN  NaN
```

In case of row 3 and 4

```
NaN  0    3    6    7    NaN
NaN  3    8    4    11   NaN
```

And then perform the operation.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range():
process[1,:] = df.iloc[i,:]
process[2,:] = df.iloc[i+1,:]
    while True:
        if process[1,:].count() == process[2,:].count():
            break
        else:
            if process[1,:].count() > process[2,:].count():
                process[2,:] = process[2,:].fillna(value = 0, limit = process[1,:].count() - process[2,:].count())
            else:
                process[2,:] = process[2,:].fillna(value = 0, limit = process[2,:].count() - process[1,:].count())                
    A[i,:] = stats.ttest_rel(process[1,:].values, process[2,:].values) #this line is just for the statistical test, you can ignore it
    i += 1
```

My algorithm didn't work, and I feel that they are somehow too clumsy by checking row and row over and over again.

Any suggestion and correction are welcome, thank you very much.

P/s: I want to consecutively perform a statistical test of every row to each other, so before doing so, I need to make them have equal numbers of non-NaN value.

Comment: What about the 3rd and 4th row?

Comment: because this is just a small part of my algorithm, I don't want to include too many things not directly related to the question.
After performing latter operations, there will be a loop to keep comparing their length and process them.

Comment: To many unanswerable questions in your code...why is `j+=1` and `i+=1` there, why is there a loop for j, it is never once used.  What is `A`? a list? a numpy Array. please read [mcve] and reword this question. It is currently unanswerable

Comment: I have edited my code. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can come up with the answer and I want to share it here:

```
for i in range(5):
    process = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    process = process.append(df.iloc[i,:], ignore_index = True)
    process = process.append(df.iloc[i+1,:], ignore_index = True)
    while True:
        if process.iloc[0,:].count() == process.iloc[1,:].count():
            break
        else:
            if process.iloc[0,:].count() > process.iloc[1,:].count():
                process.iloc[1,:] = process.iloc[1,:].fillna(value = 0, limit = process.iloc[0,:].count() - process.iloc[1,:].count())
            else:
                process.iloc[0,:] = process.iloc[0,:].fillna(value = 0, limit = process.iloc[1,:].count() - process.iloc[0,:].count())                
    i += 1
```